# USB virtual com port

Tags: usb, serial-port

How do I recognize which com port I need for a connection with INAV, Betaflight, Cleanflight. My PC recognizes the com port I need automatically; my laptop doesn't recognize it.

Comment: More information needed = Laptop Model/specs, PC Model_+/Specs. and Virtual Comm over what transport

Comment: @BJsgoodlife I suggest asking a new question. Include the output of `dmesg -n 15` afer just plugging in the USB serial adapter, and `lsusb -t`. This question is not very good in my opinion :)

Comment: I dont know that a link to /dev/ttyS0 would work, but I think an alias for a com port could work. is it software looking for com1?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if the serial communication is successful it means that you installed the drivers (on the main page of clean flight).
So you have to install the drivers on the laptop if you did not do that yet. 
The other reason i think it might be is that you have not uploaded the software inside the flight controller yet. You need to go on the Firmware Flasher and select the appropriate Firmware Then select No reboot sequence, Flash on connect and full chip erase. Then when you connect your drone make sure you are accessing the boot mode (could be a button or two pins where you need to put a wire to connect them).

if the laptop is running ubuntu try typing "hwinfo --short" It will output a list of all devices with names and ports connected.
The end of my list gives "/dev/ttyUSB0    Prolific PL2303 Serial port" and that is the device i have connected.

**DOSBOX**
So running your app in a DOSBox i would need to type "serial1 directserial realport:ttyUSB0" in the dosbox terminal to make the app able to connect to COM1.

**WINE**
But most likely you are running the app under WINE and you would have to make a ttyUSB0 redirect to a COM port.
wine does not support USB drivers, but if your device is being recognised as a serial device, and I think it is, then you need a symbolic link between com1 and /dev/usb and it must be in the folder ~/.wine/dosdevices

This will allow windows programs running under wine to see usb serial devices.

This should do it.

ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1

see
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.p...66#post4969966